# interfaces in typescript: use function parameter on a nested object reference

Tags: node.js, typescript, object, interface

I have this object model:

```
export interface UpdateDocument {
    updated_at?: string;
    actions?: Actions;
}

export interface Actions {
    update?: Update;
    create?: Create;
}

export interface Update {
    name?: Values;
    priority?: Values;
    engine?: Values;
    fact?: Fact;
}

export interface Fact {
    brand?: Values;
    model?: Values;
    version?: Values;
    year?: Values;
    km?: Values;
    color?: Values;
}

export interface Values {
    old?: any;
    new?: any;
}

export interface Create {
    conditions?: Object;
    recipe?: Object;
}
```

In this function i tried to pass a parameter to references an objects field and do an assignment:

```
async buildUpdateDocument (updateDocument: UpdateDocument) {
        
        let fields: Array<string> = ['name','priority','engine','fact','adjustment'];
        

        fields.forEach((field: string) =>{
            updateDocument.actions!.update![field]!.old = await this.getValue(field)
        })

}
```

but i hav this ts-error: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Update'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Update'.ts(7053)

How can i pass the parameter in this kind of reference to do the assignment?

Comment: One thing to consider, having an `await` in a forEach can cause problems, as the foreach will immediately resolved and the code will not await. It is good practice to wrap in a `Promise.all(yourforeach)` to ensure all promises resolve. In reality im not even sure if you do need the await here as I dont have enough context,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the modified function to better fit TS standards. This also addresses the forEach-async problem in the original code. The real correct structure would be null checks for each of the `x | undefined` types, but to override the type errors the following is the way to go.

```
async function buildUpdateDocument (updateDocument: UpdateDocument) {
  const fields: Array<keyof Update> = ['name','priority','engine','fact'];
  await Promise.all(fields.map(async (field) => {
    (((updateDocument.actions as {update: Update}).update)[field] as Values).old = await this.getValue(field);
  }));
}
```

Comment: I don't think that this is a good solution, as your `fields` and `field` are still typed to contain arbitrary strings.

Comment: @MaxYankov you're right. modified the types to take that in to account :) nice catch

Answer (score 1):

First of you have specified a wrong key `adjustment` that doesn't exist on `Update`. This example uses a explicit type (`as const`):

```
let fields = ['name','priority','engine','fact'] as const;
```

Make sure to not add a type definition to the variable when using `as const`.

Answer (score -1):

Your current code has bugs that the type system would help you find if you let it. First, the `adjustment` field doesn't exist on the `Update` type, and `old` field doesn't exist on the `Fact` type.

To implement this properly, I would use a `Record` for the data type instead:

```
const updateFields = ['name', 'priority', 'engine', 'fact'] as const
export type UpdateFields = typeof updateFields[number]
export type Update = Record<UpdateFields, Values>
```

And then, your function will look like this:

```
async buildUpdateDocument (updateDocument: UpdateDocument) {

        updateFields.forEach((field) =>{
            updateDocument.actions!.update![field]!.old = await this.getValue(field)
        })

}
```